# Setting default active tab for tabcontainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using tabcontainer in my project having two tabs as English and Spanish.

Tabs are as follows:

[image]

As we can see in pic, default active tab set is spanish.

I wanted it to be English.

For that i made following code:

`tcQuestion.ActiveTabIndex = "1"` this i written on pageload, as well ,

in aspx:  `<asp:TabContainer ID="tcQuestion" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" Width="90%">` i added `ActiveTabIndex="1"`

But as we can see in pic, no difference with this code. Default selection is spanish only.

For more clarity i would like to share whole code for tab container:

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tcQuestion" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" Width="90%"  >
        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="English" ID="English" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table align="center"  width="90%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="Heading" colspan="2" valign="top" >
                         <asp:Label ID="lblEnglish"  Text="Add Question" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right" class="NormalText" width="40%" valign="top" >
                             Question :
                         </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnglishQuestion" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox" Rows="7" Columns="35"  
                                TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>


        </asp:TabPanel>
         <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Spanish" >
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <table align="center"  width="90%">
                     <tr>
                         <td align="center" class="Heading" colspan="2" valign="top"  >
                             Add Question
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td align="right" class="NormalText" width="40%" valign="top" >
                             Question :
                         </td>
                         <td align="left">
                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestionSpanish" runat="server" CssClass="ThinTextBox" Rows="7" Columns="35"  
                                 TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                         </td>
                     </tr>


                 </table>
             </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:TabPanel>

    </asp:TabContainer>
```

note : Programming language does not matters to me (wheather its c# or vb.net)

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set tab index to zero (0).

```
tcQuestion.ActiveTabIndex = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tcQuestion.ActiveTabIndex = 0
```

you had given index of 2nd tab. But the index should be 0 for first tab